# Callback is never called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read articles about $digest cycle and **$scope.$apply()** as many as possible, but couldn't get to the point how to change my data on the callback.

This is my method:

```
vm.showAllResults = showAllResults;

function showAllResults(){
            // Prevent 'bubbling'
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
            // Second parameter notifies search to show full list of elements
            vm.search(vm.input.query, true);
            $scope.$apply(function(){
                vm.showAll = false;
            });
        }
```

**vm.search(vm.input.query, true)** - is doing some **async** work with **vm.showAll** too. **Afterwards** I want to set it as false.

But I can't get inside of $scope.$apply(). What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error? If so, what is it?

Comment: Is `vm.search` doing any _asynchronous_ work?

Comment: Hi, no I don't. Simply I am never at this line: vm.showAll = false;

Comment: Sergiu Paraschiv. Yes. It does.

Comment: Why you are not using promises?

Comment: And I'm guessing you are changing `vm.showAll` in `vm.search`, right?

Comment: I tried to use then(), but it will be only called at next $digest cycle, so never for me..

Comment: Sergiu Paraschiv. Yes, man. You're rigth one more time. That's why I need to use a callback.

Comment: But that's not how things work. Nothing can guarantee that the anonymous function you pass to `$scope.$apply` is called _after_ the asynchronous work done by `vm.search` is complete. For that you need to pass it as a callback to `vm.search` or, even better, use a promise.

Comment: And no, there's nothing wrong with AngularJS or `$apply`. Something else is happening in your code that we don't see.

Comment: Sergiu Paraschiv. Do I need to write smth like this: var promise = vm.search(vm.input.query, true).$promise.then(function(){

            });

            return promise; ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63347/discussion-between-user3722943-and-sergiu-paraschiv).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly: I'm strongly suspect that you're getting the console.error:

> $apply already in progress

which causes the $apply callback to not run.

That said, you can get around that by using [$timeout( cb )](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) instead of $scope.$apply( cb ). Be sure to dependency inject it if you want to use it:

```js
vm.showAllResults = showAllResults;

function showAllResults(){
  // Prevent 'bubbling'
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Second parameter notifies search to show full list of elements
  vm.search(vm.input.query, true);
  $timeout(function(){
    vm.showAll = false;
  });
}
```

However, as Avraam pointed out, in my opinion as well, vm.search should be a deferred method using [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) (also dependency injected) which returns a promise, and calls .resolve/reject, which you use with .then like this:

```js
vm.showAllResults = showAllResults;

function showAllResults(){
  // Prevent 'bubbling'
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Second parameter notifies search to show full list of elements
  vm.search(vm.input.query, true)
    .then( function() {
      $timeout( function() { // <-- This $timeout probably not needed...
        vm.showAll = false;      
      });
    });
}
```